# Can I force render order of directives in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Can I force the order in which angular directives render?

My HTML:

```
<body>
   <my-menu></my-menu>
   <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

The directive has a controller (simplified):

```
var myMenuController = function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('someCustomEvent', function(event, argument) {
        // Do something
    });
};
```

And the state has a controller:

```
var someStateController = function($scope) {
    $scope.$emit('someCustomEvent', argument);
};
```

However, on initial load, the `someStateController` runs before `myMenuController`, so the listener doesn't catch the first `$scope.$emit()`. If I navigate to another page that also calls `$scope.$emit()`, it works. I could use `$timeout`, but then there's a delay.

Comment: have you tried setting a priority?

Comment: @pankajparkar This works, though. Just not initial load.

Comment: @aw04 How would I go about doing that?

Comment: There's a priority(numeric) you can set on a directive (so in your menu, priority: xxx), but on second thought I don't think it will help in your case. It only makes sense for when you have multiple directives on the same DOM element.

Comment: I've recreated what seems to be your setup at http://plnkr.co/edit/GvLonDpK1Q8lC2jRjuxy?p=preview, but the listener seems to work on initial load. Can you modify it so it shows your issue?

Comment: @LittleBigBot could you try to emit event in `$timeout` function like `$timeout(function(){  $scope.$emit('someCustomEvent', argument); })` so that it will call on next digest cycle

Comment: Thanks @MichalCharemza, I'm having the opposite problem with your plunkr, in that I can't get the directive to run after.